# How to remove an app request using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I'm trying to remove app requests using an HTTP POST request to:
    https://graph.facebook.com/288041244541781_100000461597474?access_token=AT&method=delete
The access token i'm using is from the signed_request object.

However, when doing so I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#2) App Request Recipient Must Be Specified: The recipient for this app request must be specified through a user-signed access token or the fully specified app request ID.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

I think I supplied the fully specified app request ID, but I can't seem to find what the difference is between a user-signed access token and the token I'm using.
How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Does the access token look correct in the linter tool and has the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
  $reqs = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);
  foreach($reqs as $req) {
    $url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$req."?access_token=";
    $url .= $facebook->getAccessToken()."&method=delete";
    $result = file_get_contents($delete_url);
  }
}
```